# How to receive URL File as parameter and save it to disk using FastAPI?

Tags: python, download, fastapi, starlette

I would like to know if there is a way for FastAPI to receive a URL of a file as a parameter and save this file to disk? I know it is possible with the `requests` library using `requests.get()` method, but is it possible with FastAPI to receive the URL and save it directly?

I tried using `file: UploadFile = File(...)`, but then it doesn't download the file when the URL is sent.

Comment: Could you specify what you would like to accomplish in more detail, maybe include a pseudocode example? It's a bit difficult to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: No, you need to pass `bytes` or `UploadFile`.

Comment: Please take a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804).

Comment: Good, I applied it here with httpx... which is recommended by fastapi. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. I've come across this before and was unable to find a solution (and ended up using requests like you mentioned), but seeing this I wanted to check again more thoroughly.

Reviewing the `uvicorn` and `fastapi`  repositories by searching the code itself, I see no functions/code that reference `requests` or `urllib` (they do use `urllib.parse`/`quote`, etc though) that would be 2 likely suspects to build requests. They do use `httpx.AsyncClient`, but only in tests. I would expect to see some use of these libraries in the main `uvicorn`/`fastapi` libraries if they had code to make external requests.

Seeing the above, I actually think I will change my code to use `httpx.AsyncClient` anyways since it is already a dependency.

Comment: I didn't find anything either, I ended up using request.get anyway...