# How to stream an S3 bucket video from FastAPI to Vue JS?

Tags: python, vue.js, fastapi

Error occured while returning the streaming response from FastAPI, unable to bind into vuejs video-player library since it required src to play a video. Can you help me to solve this problem ?

[image]
I have tried api call to download the stream response in vuejs.

```
    async videoDownload() {
      var url = '/api/v1/docs/1955/video'
      const resp = await this.axios.get(url);
      console.log("Video is streaming live !!")
      this.videoOptions.sources[0].src = resp;
      this.showvideo = true
    },
```

Comment: A presigned can be use to generate a url with the help of boto3 client and this url can be return and this url directly bind with video player src and video can be start playing.

Comment: You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) helpful