# FastAPI response video to Axios

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, fastapi

Hi I want to make noise reduction from video. I post video from client-side React with axios, I processed video data. But I couldn't send back to client with FastApi. I used FileResponse, data is sending but I couldn't show taken video in the React app.

this is my backend code

```
@app.post('/videoProcess')
async def process_video(video: UploadFile=File(...)):
    video_file=await video.read()
    with open('temp/video_data.mp4','wb+')as f:
        f.write(video_file)
    # video processing here
    response = FileResponse('temp/final_video.mp4', media_type='video/mp4')
    return response
```

this is my frontend code

```
const handleVideoSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        updateLoading(true);
        if (sendVideo) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('video', sendVideo);
            const response = await axios.post('url/videoProcess', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });
            const videoBlob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'video/mp4' });
            const videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
            updateLoading(false);
            toast('Video Başarılı Bir Şekilde İşlendi.');
            setProcessedVideo(videoUrl);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error submitting video:', error);
        toast(error.message);
        updateLoading(false);
    }
};
```

This is my show video code:

```
               return(
                <div style={{ position: 'relative', maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '750px' }}>
                    <video
                        controls
                        style={{
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '750px',
                            top: 0,
                            left: 0
                        }}
                    >
                        <source src={processedVideo} type="video/mp4" />
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
                )
```

Where am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804) helpful